# How to create a category for class UIWebDocumentView from private API?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, categories

How to create a category for class UIWebDocumentView from private API?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIWebDocumentView (myCanPerformAction)

- (BOOL)myCanPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender;

@end
```

The error:

> Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIWebDocumentView'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on ios.... define it on NSObject

on osx... one could use reflection to add methods at runtime